# after V8 is JS interpreted or compiled?

Tags: javascript, v8

i read some articles about interpreted Vs Compiled languages 
and i came with conclusion that the main difference is compiled goes to native directly(without any intermediate bytecode) that's what interpreted can't do 
however i continue my readings and i found and article that says
" It compiles JavaScript code into machine code at execution by implementing a JIT (Just-In-Time) compiler like a lot of modern JavaScript engines such as SpiderMonkey or Rhino (Mozilla) are doing. The main difference with V8 is that it doesn’t produce bytecode or any intermediate code." 
now with V8 does this make JS compiled language ? since it generates machine code directly does that make JS platform-dependant? 
and how does JIT work ?

Comment: It's still the interpreter that jit-compiles the code (from source to native), the code is distributed not some sort of bytecode or executable.

Comment: Where did you read that V8 doesn't produce bytecode or any intermediate code? That's hardly true, I've never seen a serious compiler that doesn't have any intermediate data structures.

Comment: here you are ! 
https://thibaultlaurens.github.io/javascript/2013/04/29/how-the-v8-engine-works/

Comment: That's a really old and hardly accurate blog post, the particular statement is unsourced.

Comment: could you provide a new truthful one please :) ?

Comment: @Bergi  I think V8's graphic here is maybe partly due to the confusion -> https://v8.dev/blog/ignition-interpreter   I would say the arrow from ignition to full code gen, really wants to be arrow from byte code to full code gen..

Comment: `and how does JIT work ?`  The same way it works in Java / C# etc.  So the only real difference is that Javascript has the bytecode created at runtime, not compile time (as there is no compile time as such).

Comment: @Keith IIRC there's a truth in that the optimised code is not created from the interpreter bytecode, they start over from the AST (or even from the function code string), to save on memory because there's a lot of code that only runs once and would be too heavy to keep around. But these steps are optimised for different use cases from year to year, I'm not certain the graphic from 2016 is still up-to date…

Comment: check this out: http://voidcanvas.com/is-javascript-really-interpreted-or-compiled-language/

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is still an interpreted language and platform independent.

Every language has to be compiled to byte code at some point as that is the only code the machine can execute.

The difference to a compiled language is that an interpreted language is compiled chunkwise at run time. This type of compiling is called interpreting as it does nothing more than convert the code to bytecode without checking for errors. Compiled languages are compiled completely before the program can be executed, and have the added benefit of the compiler checking for errors.

The platform dependency of the byte code is completely handled by the V8 engine you don't have to worry about any other platform besides different browser versions.

Edit: i found an article that explains exactly your question: http://voidcanvas.com/is-javascript-really-interpreted-or-compiled-language/

Comment: "*an interpreted language is compiled chunkwise at run time*" - um, no. It just means that the bytecode is interpreted by a an interpreter program, not natively by the CPU.

Comment: Poor wording on my side, sorry. With compile i generally mean translate human readable code to byte code. However i did not know that this byte code is then not directly executed by the CPU, interesting.